# The activities are 'in line' or 'aligned' with the needs?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

Which is the correct word to use to imply that the activities are chosen regarding to the needs?

> I would be happy to communicate the matters discussed in the meetings with all students, which will guarantee the activities of the Student Association are *in-line/aligned* with the students' needs.

Is there another more suitable word to use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To “align” is to *make* something be “in line” with something else.

If the Student Association is choosing their activities to match what students need, “aligned” would be the better choice. If they’re merely commenting that their choices happened to turn out that way, then “in line” works better.

- The plan is aligned with our objectives.
- The results are in line with our forecast.

Answer (score 1):

I think 'aligned' is a fine word to use here.

I would use "in line" instead of "in-line"; "in line with the students' needs" means the same thing as "aligned with the students' needs".

Congratulations on correct use of the apostrophe as the plural possessive...